# dropdownlist is not posting the data in code behind while selection of value

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have dropdown inside my asp page and when i am trying to select value then cannt able to get the value in code behind.

Here is my dropdown list code :

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">   
<div class="row" >
              <asp:Label ID="LblLanguage" runat="server" Text="Label" meta:resourceKey="LblLanguage">Language</asp:Label>
             <asp:DropDownList ID="Language1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="auto">Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="en-US">English (US)</asp:ListItem>
               <asp:ListItem Value="fr">French</asp:ListItem>
             </asp:DropDownList>
            </div>
</asp:Content>
```

When i try to select French language from dropdown then code behind no values.Here is my code behind

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {

        string lang = Request["Language1"];
        
            if (lang != null && lang != string.Empty)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lang);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(lang);
        }
    }
```

So here string lang is having null even i selected a value from dropdown.

Comment: But with autopostbacck = true, then the event in code behind that fires is SelectedIndexChanged. I don't get why you using InitializeCulture? Unless the post-back has fired, then only after that postback occurs can you get/grab the value of the dropdown list.  You don't explain when/where/how this additional code stub is going to be run and when it will be run? when is InitializeCulture expected to run?

Comment: @Albert D. Kallal InitializeCulture will change the language of the form.when page initialize then for sure dropdown need to intialize that's.With the help of selection we can change the language?

Comment: @NCCSBIM071 - last time i used you solution and it was working in my new application.I use same solution in an existing form.There is some issue during selection of value from dropdown.Will you able to help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reference the dropdown Language1 in the old ASP classic way. To obtain the value of your dropdown reference it as Language1.SelectedValue.

```
string lang = Request["Language1"];
```

should be

```
string lang = Language1.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: I already tried SelectedValue but it gives error when you load the page because no values selected that time.So my code is initializing the value for string "lang".

Comment: If i replace my code
 with your lines then it gives error "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

Comment: Where is InitializeCulture being called from? If you are calling it from PageLoad before any of the controls on the page have been given values, then SelectedValue would be null. The behavior of InitializeCulture must take into account whether you are on initial page load, where IsPostBack is false, or whether it is a post back, where IsPostBack is true. On initial page load you need get the value for culture from a session variable or some other persistent storage mechanism.

Comment: InitializeCulture  automatically before page load as its written before page_load.So its intialize the values of language and conert accordingly.Actually dropdown is there inside content place holder .if i use normal asp.net web form then this code is working there but here its not posting selected value in code behind

Comment: I think there is a language barrier here Vim. I have a lot of trouble understanding what you write. Perhaps someone who speaks your language could be more helpful to you. I think what you mean is that after the page loads and you change the language choice to "French", The InitializeCulture routine sees the SelectedValue property of Language1 as null. This is likely because other code that is firing before where InitilizeCulture is called from is clearing the selected value by rebinding the control or something.

Comment: No Dave , actually my same code is working for another web form where values easily post in code behind but here when i use same dropdownlist inside a content place holder then the selected value is not sending to code behind using Request["Language1"] inside InitializeCulture(). But if i take a normal web form then my code is working perfectly.